# how do you read and print entire sting in python

Tags: python

A friend and I is having some trouble with this code, When we run it and type a Morsecode, it prints only E and T, so it only reads the first char..
We have tried rewriting the DECODE segment cause we thought it might be that, but after 3 tries and multiple google searches.. We now ask you guys for help

```
    DECODE = {
    '.-':'A',       '-...':'B',     '-.-.':'C',
    '-..':'D',      '.':'E',        '..-.':'F',
    '--.':'G',      '....':'H',     '..':'I',
    '.---':'J',     '-.-':'K',      '.-..':'L',
    '--':'M',       '.-':'N',       '---':'O',
    '.--.':'P',     '--.-':'Q',     '.-.':'R',
    '...':'S',      '-':'T',        '..-':'U',
    '...-':'V',     '.--':'W',      '-..-':'X',
    '-.--':'Y',     '--..':'Z',

    '-----': '0',   '.----': '1',   '..---': '2',
    '...--': '3',   '....-': '4',   '.....': '5',
    '-....': '6',   '--...': '7',   '---..': '8',
    '----.': '9',   '//': ' ',

def main1():

    msg1 = raw_input('Input morsecode: ')

    for char in msg1:
        print DECODE[char.upper()],

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main1()
```

Thank

Comment: Morse code actually has four symbols, not two: [dash, dot,  inter-letter pause, and inter-word pause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code). Without adding these extra two symbols, you cannot tell when a letter begins and ends. For example if I see `.-` is it `A` or the beginning of `J` (`.---`)

Answer (score 1):

When you get the input you need to split it. Say, for example, the user inputed :

```
.- .----
```

You need to split the spaces so you get a list of each morse code character :

```
msgChars = msg1.split(" ")
```

That will output msgChars as a list of every character in the morse code :

```
[".-", ".----"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split the message. Here's an example in Python 3. Didn't have Python 2 readily available. Sorry about that.

```
morse_map = {
    '.-':'A', '-..':'D', '--.':'G', '.---':'J', '--':'M', '.--.':'P', 
    '...':'S', '...-':'V', '-.--':'Y', '..---':'2', '...--':'3', 
    '-....':'6', '----.':'9', '-.-.':'C', '..-.':'F', '..':'I', 
    '.-..':'L', '---':'O', '.-.':'R', '..-':'U', '-..-':'X', 
    '-----':'0', '.....':'5', '---..':'8', '-...':'B', '.':'E', 
    '....':'H', '-.-':'K', '.-':'N', '--.-':'Q', '-':'T', '.--':'W', 
    '--..':'Z', '.----':'1', '....-':'4', '--...':'7', '//':' '
}

def main():
    msg = input('Input morsecode: ')

    for char in msg.split(' '):
        print(morse_map[char], end="")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example input/output:

```
Input morsecode: . .. -... // . . .-.
EIB EER
```